# reference top or parent top in CSS calc

Tags: css

I want to expand a div to exactly fit the rest of the screen without causing a scrollbar to appear.

I know questions like this have been asked *many* times before, but I can't find an acceptable answer - almost everything I find requires knowing something else - how high the header is for example -

but what occurred to me is that I really want to do this:

```css
    height : calc( 100vh - {absolute position of top} );
```

which of course doesn't work...
I know how to do it in javascript - but is there a way in just css to make a div fill "the rest of the space" without knowing (or structuring) anything about the rest of the space in advance?

Comment: Answering your secondary question — the easiest way to have an element fill up the remaining space is `flex-grow: 1` inside a `display: flex` element.

Comment: yeah - I've read that a lot - but it doesn't work at all - it just pushes the problem up one level.     if you do:

 <div style="display:flex">
  <div style="flex-grow:1;background-color:green">
    hi
  </div>
  </div>

you just get a green line one line high and wonder... "how do I get my parent element to fill the remaining space"

Comment: you should show some code to understand what you want better, show some html markup, show the expected vs current behavior